# Android httpURLConnection already running

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, disconnect

I've got an app where in I was calling an httpURLConnection with the requestproperty connection "stay-alive".
Because I didn't call the HttpURLConnection.disconnect() when my app was crashing, he didn't make it to the disconnect call because I didn't put it in the finally method.

### Problem

When I rerun my app, I see that my url.openConnection() already see the old HttpUrlConnection and take that back out of the pool. Problem now is that I can't simply kill the already existed connection.

After some research on the web I found an old bug report (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2939)
I already tried different approaches, but after the url.openConnection() calling httpURLConnection.disconnect() didn't do anthing. Reinstall app, reboot pc and tablet also weren't effective.

### Known exceptions

- java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected

### Question

So my question is: How can I kill the existed HttpURLConnection?

Here a brief example of the **wrong** used code:

```
try{
        File file = new File("resources/test.png");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        URL url = new URL(urlRequest);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); 

        //Get Cookie from session
        String key = MyHttpClient.sharedInstance().getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0).getName();
        String value = MyHttpClient.sharedInstance().getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0).getValue();

        //allow inputs & outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        //Enable GET method
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "MyAgent");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", key+"="+value);

        //Call with stream fields
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;


        //Call with stream
        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        /*outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\""+ Configuration.userTempImage.getPath()+ "\""+lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);*/

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        //Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0 , bufferSize);

        while(bytesRead > 0){
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        /*outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);*/


        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = readAll(rd);

        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        System.out.print(serverResponseCode + " - " + serverResponseMessage+" -> ");
    } catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

And this is my **updated** code

```
private static String getImagePath(String urlRequest){
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

    // ?
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    // The connection to the server
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    // The data steam for sending the file to the server
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    // A file stream to read the local file.
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    // ?
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = null;
    // Cropped image file
    File croppedImage = null;

    try{
        try{
            stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Configuration.userTempBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            // Close the output-stream
            if(stream != null) { stream.close(); }

            croppedImage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.jpg");

            if(croppedImage.exists()){
                croppedImage.delete();
            }

            fos = new FileOutputStream(croppedImage);
            fos.write(byteArray);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
        } finally {
            if(fos != null) { fos.close(); }
        }

        //Get Cookie from session
        String key = MyHttpClient.sharedInstance().getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0).getName();
        String value = MyHttpClient.sharedInstance().getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0).getValue();

        URL url = new URL(urlRequest);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        //Allow inputs & outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true); // <-- Exception is thrown here
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Set connection properties
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", key+"="+value);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "MyAgent");

        // Set connection headers
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000);

        //Call with stream fields
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

        // Create an input stream to the cropped image file
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(croppedImage);
        // Create an output stream to send the file to the server
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        //Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0 , bufferSize);

        while(bytesRead > 0){
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // Be sure to send everything
        outputStream.flush();

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();


        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = RequestHelper.readAll(rd);

        return jsonText;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try{
            if(fileInputStream != null) { fileInputStream.close(); }
            if(outputStream != null) { outputStream.close(); }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(connection != null) { connection.disconnect(); }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```